# SPFx: Customize field behavior similar to JSLink in classic list forms

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extensions, fieldcustomizers

We use jslink on the field to customize the UI and behavior of fields on classic SharePoint forms and list views (cascading, colors etc.). How can we make this work in the Sharepoint modern experience using sharepoint framework?

I have gone through  this [Microsoft Tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/guidance/migrate-from-jslink-to-spfx-extensions) on migrating JSLink to Sharepoint Framework Extensions using Field Customizer. But this only customizes the field rendering in a list view. Is there a way to render the field on the new form using Field Customizer or some other way using Sharepoint Framework.

Comment: Unfortunately, only the listview display is available for customization using SPFx Field Customizers currently. However, there is a uservoice suggestion for it here: https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329220-sharepoint-dev-platform/suggestions/20474935-field-customizer-evolution-forms-quick-edit-mode (Go vote!)